# Hessian null - Point of saddle

Tags: real-analysis, education

Given the function $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x,\,y,\,z) := 3 x y^2 + 6 y^2 + x^2 z + 3 z^2 $ is not difficult to show that $f$ presents a unique critical point of coordinates $(0,\,0,\,0)$.

Unfortunately the Hessian matrix of $f$ in this point is positive semidefinite, then this point is relative minimum or "saddle".

Limiting restrictions $f(x,\,0,\,0) = 0, \; f(0,\,y,\,0) = 6y^2, \;  f(0,\,0,\,z) = 3z^2$, I can state that this $(0,\,0,\,0)$ is a "saddle"'s point for $f$ because in the first restriction there is no critical point while in the second (and also in the third) in the origin there is a point of relative minimum?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The local minimum value, if it is one, would be $0$. Try setting $y = 0$ and then see what happens if you set $z = x^3$ for negative $x$ arbitrarily close to $0$.

Comment: @Manu If $x < 0$ and $|x| < \epsilon$ where $\epsilon > 0$ is small enough, then $3x^6 + x^5 \simeq x^5 < 0$. So you can't have a local minimum value of 0 at the critical point $(0,0,0)$. That was all I was trying to say.